# Parsing bytes in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on an output file from an experiment that has a very specific formatting (sample data below). Basically, the file contains two types of data -- the header and the data. The data should be read 4 bytes (32-bits) at a time and those bytes need to be further parsed (see figures) because each set of bits represent something significant about the data. For instance, in the Data event picture, the first 11-13 bits are reserved for ADC data. The first part of the problem is very easy. However, I am facing issues in parsing those 4 bytes and assigning them. The Python code will distinguish between headers and data through the flags hsig (b01) and dsig (b00).

[image: Event header]
[image: Data event]

Data from sample file:

4d56 4d45 0100 0000 3215 0000 7b0a 2020
2020 2244 4151 436f 6e66 6967 223a 207b
0a20 2020 2020 2020 2022 656e 6162 6c65
6422 3a20 7472 7565 2c0a 2020 2020 2020
2020 2265 7665 6e74 7322 3a20 5b0a 2020
2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 7b0a 2020 2020
2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2265 6e61
626c 6564 223a 2074 7275 652c 0a20 2020

So far I have been able to read the data 4 bytes at a time. I was thinking if there was a way to treat the read bytes as an array or list so that I could assign it to certain variables.

```
f = open("sample_file",'rb')

while True:
    f_line = f.read(4) # read 4 bytes at a time

# if I could treat f_line as a string, then the last three elements would be dsig (b00) or 
# hsig (b01)  
    if f_line[-1:-3] == b00:
        ADC_reading = f_line[0:13]
        ...
        ...
        ....
    elif f_line[-1:-3] == b01:
        ...
        ....

    if not f_line:
        break

f.close()
```

Any help or guidance would be highly appreciated!

Comment: By `b00` do you mean the two-byte string you can specify as `b'\0\0'`?

Comment: What format is the file in?  What is not working about your current approach?  f_line[-1:-3] looks odd to me, why not f_line[0:3]?

Comment: you should be using the `struct` module for this

Comment: Or maybe you want something like `list(f_line)[0] >> 6` to take the first byte out of the 4-byte string and then shift it by 6 bits, leaving you with the first two (which will be 0 or 1)?

Comment: also, you could use the `ctypes` module to build views around the raw structure that you can mutate and inspet easily as python objets

Comment: the `bytes` type is immutable. You could convert to a `bytearray` or `memoryview`, but again, you really should just use `struct` and/or `ctypes`

Comment: "Data from sample file:" your data is just raw bytes, correct? It's hard to tell, because that looks like a hexdump. Why don't you just provide use the python `bytes` representation so it can be unambiguous.

Comment: I don't think `struct` does bitfields, and getting anything useful done with `struct` here would need bitfield support.

Comment: @Samwise yes if you look at the diagrams posted, 00 and 01 are two bits of byte #3.

Comment: @Pete since the header and data signatures are at byte #3 (and not byte #0), I thought we need to go backwards.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga could you please explain a bit more?

Answer (score 3):

You can convert to a string of zeros and ones like this:

```
bitstring = bin(int.from_bytes(f_line, byteorder="big"))
print(bitstring)
# output: 0b<bits>
```

However, this will not pad the number so, e.g. the number 8 will only give you a string "0b1000". Instead of `bin()`, you can also use `format` with a specified padding:

```
bitstring = format(int.from_bytes(f_line, byteorder="big"), '032b')
```

This will also omit the "0b" prefix.

Now you can access the individual bits using ranges.

This might not be the most performant way, but I don't know about your performance requirements.

Comment: Thank you very much! I had another question. I am trying to read 32 bits at a time (excluding the '0b' at the beginning). How do I accomplish that?

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you want to get rid of the prefix you can use `bitstring[2:]`.

Comment: Okay. In figure 1 (event header), out of 32 bits 2 bits are reserved for hsig, 6 bits are reserved for subheader etc. However, when my program reads 32 bits, isn't it actually only reading 30 bits from the data (because it adds a '0b' in the front for the 2 remaining bits)? So, in reality I am only reading 30 bits of data, when I need 32 bits of data. Isn't that right?

Comment: No, what you are saying makes no sense to me. The 0b is a formatting syntax and is prepended regardless of number of bits. It is like 0x which denotes hex numbers. But the length of the formatted number depends on the highest set bit. This is an oversight from my side. I edit my answer accordingly.